# Not able to deploy spring tiles application in Websphere 7

Tags: spring, websphere, tiles2

I am trying to deploy Spring - Tiles - Hibernate based application in WebSphere 7 application server.
After deployment server is also starting successfully. While running the application it is throwing below error -

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: null
at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader$FillDefinitionRule.begin(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:162) ~[tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1464) [commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1788) [commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:325) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURL(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:274) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:235) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:57) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:223) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadParentDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:57) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromURLs(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:223) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:205) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:188) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:151) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:119) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:53) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.apache.tiles.definition.UrlDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UrlDefinitionsFactory.java:104) [tiles-core-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:92) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:438) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:186) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:401) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:103) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1211) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1160) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173) [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) [na:CCX.CF [o0831.10]]
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) [na:CCX.CF [o0831.10]]
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:CCX.CF [o0831.10]]
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
```

My application context is having -

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/templates.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My POM.xml looks like below -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>xx.xx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>xxx</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springVersion>3.1.1.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <springSecurityVersion>3.1.0.RELEASE</springSecurityVersion>
    <tilesVersion>2.1.2</tilesVersion>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>ldapbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <classifier>all</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tilesVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tilesVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tilesVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${tilesVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any answer to the question will be a great help, as I am stuck with this issue from last 3 days !!!

Comment: Is your application running successfully without tiles?

Comment: Is your application running on an other server (tomcat 6 for example) without that problem?

Comment: I haven't tried without tiles, but by looking at the problem stack trace... yes it should work... I don't prefer to have application without tiles, but that is the next step I will be left with !!!

I have run the application on tomcat 6 and 7 both and it is running successfully.

This is the problem with WAS jar files and my lib files ... mostly some where work around with xercesImpl...

Solution to this problem would be a great help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ralph, Thanks for the help !!!

I accept your answer with bit more information -

Yes, 
I have removed xreses-impl and xalan jars from my war.

I also have removed xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar file from my WAR file, it gets added by default as dependency with dom4J 1.6.

I have added dependency for tiles-portlet

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${tilesVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I am using tiles version 2.1.2, as there are compatibility issues between other tiles 2.X versions and WAS 7.

commons-digester 2.0 is the version I am currently using.

I hope this helps to any one who is facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what exactly causes the problem, but it is related to some incompatibility.

On websphere it often help to change the class loader order for the WAR!! to "parent last"

---

In one of my projects I have also had some problems with `org.apache.xerces` on Webshpere. In this case it worked after exclude `org.apache.xerces` from shipping with the application.

"My" error was

```
by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory 
incompatible with javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:239)
```

So I never connected org.apache.xerces with your tiles problems.

BTW in the same project I used Tiles and it worked on WebSphere 7.0 (with excluded `org.apache.xerces`). But I used other Versions:

- tiles 2.2.1
- commons-digester 2.0

Comment: Hi Ralph, your doubt should be correct, is there any incompatibility between xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar and commons-digester-1.8.1.jar ?

if yes then what should be the correct compatible jars ?

And yes class loader order is Parent last ...

Comment: @Maulik: try to exclide xercesImpl complete, and see my extended answer